# Scroll an object to the right

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a `div` with an `overflow: scroll`. How can I make it scroll 20px to the right in javascript?

I tried the following but it doesn't seem work:

```
document.querySelector('div').scrollTo(20, 0);
```

It returns that `scrollTo` isn't a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollTo` is not a function. What you want to use is `scrollLeft`. This will scroll your div to the right.

```
document.querySelector('div').scrollLeft = 20;
```

If you want to scroll 20 pixels to the right every time, use `+=`

```
document.querySelector('div').scrollLeft += 20;
```

If you want to scroll vertically, use the `scrollTop` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

Comment: scrollTop is not a method

Comment: Sorry, it is a property